# What does the interface look like for an array that can contain objects with different properties?

Tags: typescript

I created the following interface and service. Note that the view property will contain an array of objects but depending on where it is used these objects WILL have different properties:

```
interface IAdminGridService  {
    view:   {any} []; // An array of objects. It could be an array of contents, 
                      // cities, streets etc. If it was an array of city objects
                      // then these objects might in themselves contain a list 
                      // of street objects. I don't need any checks here. Just 
                      // want it to be an array of any kind of object.
}

class AdminGridService implements IAdminGridService {
    view = getViewData('city'); // Returns an array of objects
}
```

In another part of the code I want to do this:

```
this.grid.view[this.home.rowSelected].tests.length > 0
```

The code correctly finds this.grid.view but gives a message saying:

```
The property 'tests' does not exist on value of type '{ any: any; }'
```

How can I make my interface more generic so that when I later have code that looks at certain properties then I won't get syntax errors like the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type definition `{any}[]` does not mean what you think it means. It means "*an array of objects that have a property named `any` whose type is `any`*". In other words, it's the same as `{any:any}[]`.

---

If the type of the stored objects is the same inside one class, you can add a type parameter like this:

```
interface IAdminGridService<T> {
  view: T[];
}

class AdminGridService implements IAdminGridService<City> {
  // this class will treat this.view as a City[]
  // where City is the type definition of the object you are putting into the array
  this.view = getViewData('city');
}
```

---

Otherwise, you can go with the untyped approach:

```
interface IAdminGridService  {
  view: any[];
}
```

and typecast the usages to the right type if possible:

```
(<City[]>this.view)[this.home.rowSelected].tests.length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `any[]` would work:

```
interface IAdminGridService  {
    view:   any[]; // An array of objects. It could be an array of contents, 
                   // cities, streets etc. If it was an array of city objects
                   // then these objects might in themselves contain a list 
                   // of street objects. I don't need any checks here. Just 
                   // want it to be an array of any kind of object.
}


var grid:IAdminGridService;
grid.view[this.home.rowSelected].tests.length > 0
```